# What does python with statement do when opening files?

Tags: python, file-io, with-statement

I think that

```
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    pass
```

closes file f, but, how can I prove it? My colleague thinks it will flush the file if it is open for writing.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: actually, https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/compound_stmts.html#with

Comment: see the answer: you are both correct

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation clearly states that files will be closed once the with statement is exited.](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

However, if that is not proof enough - here is a way you can check for yourself;

[Files](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/bltin-file-objects.html) have a `.closed` property that you can check.

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    print(f.closed)  # will print False
print(f.closed)  # will print True
```

The same property can be used when dealing with files the non-`with` way.

```
f = open("file.txt", "r")
print(f.closed)  # will print False
f.close()
print(f.closed)  # will print True.
```

This should service as sufficient proof that the file is indeed being closed.

Comment: Yes: close implies flush. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447143/does-close-imply-flush-in-python